# Change Plasma 5 Digital Clock to 24 Format

Tags: linux, kde, kde-plasma-workspace

I recently made the update to Plasma 5 from Plasma 4 and while the transition has been mostly smooth, there is one thing that is bugging the heck out of me: the digital clock.

This seems like a major downgrade from the one provided in Plasma 4. My problem is simple. I prefer my time in 24hr format, but whoever developed this plasmoid neglected to provide this very basic function. Come to think of it, I have never used a desktop environment that did not provide this.

So the only option I have found is to change my locale settings to something other than en_US, which is a ridiculous thing to have to do. Moreover, changing my locale to say en_GB changes my date format, which is not what I want. This would all be tolerable if not for the following issue I run into when running say 'perl':

```
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LC_TIME = "C.UTF-8",
    LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to a fallback locale ("en_US.UTF-8").
```

My experience with 'locale-gen' is fairly limited. I basically use it once during the installation of my OS. Is there a way to fix it using 'locale-gen' or something similar?

Or preferably, does anyone have a better solution to changing my time format to 24 hours that does not involve the extreme measure of changing my locale, which requires me to logout and log back in in order to take effect by the way.

Answer (score 0):

I go the locale way:Backup your /etc/locale.conf file.
do

> locale > /etc/locale.conf

Edit the locale.conf file appropriately (eg. lang set to en_US but time to en_GB)

All used locales (in this case en_US and en_GB) uncomment in /etc/locale.gen and run locale-gen.

Reboot.

EDIT: Make sure to always use the .UTF-8 (iso would work too, is not recommended though)